# Track Individual User Page Visits

Tags: users

Drupal 7 - Is there an easy way to track individual user page visits using Google Analytics or can I just do this within Drupal?

Answer (score 8):

Worth noting that tracking individual users is against the [Google Analytics terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html):

> 7.PRIVACY . You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track or collect personally identifiable information of
>   Internet users, nor will You (or will You allow any third party to)
>   associate any data gathered from Your website(s) (or such third
>   parties' website(s)) with any personally identifying information from
>   any source as part of Your use (or such third parties' use) of the
>   Service. You will have and abide by an appropriate privacy policy and
>   will comply with all applicable laws relating to the collection of
>   information from visitors to Your websites. You must post a privacy
>   policy and that policy must provide notice of your use of a cookie
>   that collects anonymous traffic data.

However, Drupal can track authenticated users using the core statistics module.

More info:

- [statistics_node_tracker](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.pages.inc/function/statistics_node_tracker/7)
- [statistics_user_tracker](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.pages.inc/function/statistics_user_tracker/7)
- [statistics documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics)

Comment: Keep in mind that the statistics module can be a drain on site performance. But, it does what it says it does.